# How can I change the value of an element in a list which belongs to a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures, tuples

I have a dictionary of tuples as keys and lists as valued called *dictionary* as shown below from which I only wanna change the values of the elements in the list that are 67. For instance the second element of the list which belongs to the key (1,2,3). I have written the following code but I get an error saying „list indices must be integers or sliced, not str“.

```
dictionary = { (1,2,3) : [234,67],
               (2,2,3) : [4,7]
}


for i in dictionary:
    for j in i:
        if dictionary[i][j] == 67:
           dictionary[i][j] = 50
```

Could someone help me understand what I am doing wrong ? I am really desperate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of errors in your code but this should work:

```
for i in dictionary:
    for j in range(len(dictionary[i])):
        if dictionary[i][j] == 67:
            dictionary[i][j] = 50
```

In your code, `for j in i` is referring to the numbers in dictionary keys. This can't be changed.

Answer (score 3):

`==` is for comparisons; `=` is for assignments. However, you also have a bug in how you treat `i`. `i` is a key like `(1,2,3)`, but you are treating it like the value `dictionary[i]`. If you want to modify a list, you also need an index into the list, so using `enumerate` will help.

```
for i in dictionary:  # i is tuple like (1,2,3)
    # enumerate(dictionary[i]) yields a sequence of tuples
    # like (0, 234), (1, 67)
    for j, value in enumerate(dictionary[i]):
        if value == 67:
            dictionary[i][j] = 50
```

Just like `enumerate` gives you an index and a value from a list, you can use the `items` method to get both a key and value while iterating over a `dict`.

```
# list_value stands in for dictionary[i]
for i, list_value in dictionary.items():
    for j, value in enumerate(list_value):
        if value == 67:
            list_value[j] = 50
```